# File upload keeps failing

Tags: php, mysql

Keep having this same issue when uploading filed - I have debugged but see the following error I am stumped??

somewhere between the point of pasing the data and requesting it to be moved to permanent location it disappears

```
Debug: ++ DB QUERY SUCCESSFUL

Passed file detials
array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "dblogo.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpy3ZPgA" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(30182) } }
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/I8DfTdUehInQGjlp.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/file_upload.php on line 59 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpy3ZPgA' to '/images/I8DfTdUehInQGjlp.png' in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/file_upload.php on line 59

File move results:
Debug: ++ FAILED TO MOVE FILE FROM /tmp/phpy3ZPgA TO /images/I8DfTdUehInQGjlp.png ++
```

Comment: Are you sure the file was written?

Comment: please format your question!

Comment: @jmeier - The question surely dosnt require any formatting?

Comment: @JAL - all the signs say yes to a temp file but because it happens tos quickly  there is no way to check the dir

Comment: I've added some formatting for you.

Comment: You could add some code to check the file is there before trying to move it. Also, a possibility is that the target directory is not writable by the web server.

Comment: @JAL - Do you have any suggestions as to what code?

Comment: Add an 'echo filesize($whatever_tmp_location_is);' perhaps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to move to `/images/`, this would be at the root of the filesystem, and likely that it doesn't exist, or doesn't have write permissions. If you're trying to save to the `images/` folder that sits in the same location as your script, remove the first `/` from the beginning of the images path.

Comment: Does the `images` directory exist already? Also, have you tried browsing to the `/tmp` folder on the filesystem, to make sure the images have successfully uploaded in the first place?

Comment: The file certainly does exist and because it happens so quickly I am unable to check to see if the image has arrived.

Comment: I mean if it exists on the server. If the script is failing to move the image, it should still be within the temp directory